# Asynchronous and EntityManager

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, glassfish-3

Is there any implications using `EntityManager` in `@Asychronous` method calls.

For example a "EJB cannot be invoked in global transaction"?

I call two methods from a bean called "Loader" for loading data asychronously right after each other.

Sometimes I get this error message.

All methods involved a tagged with `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NEVER)`

**Stacktrace:**

```
[#|2013-12-T13:54:15.394+0100|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=146;_ThreadName=Thre
ad-2;|javax.ejb.EJBException: EJB cannot be invoked in global transaction
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.preInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4626)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.preInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1914)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EjbAsyncTask.call(EjbAsyncTask.java:99)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
|#]
```

Comment: No, as far as I know. Do you use any kind of locking (optimistic or pesimistic) when you fetch the entities? As I undestand, you make only SELECT operations in those operations, is that right?

Comment: Oh, sorry. It did not use the @ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.CONTAINER)
explict. But maybe it is then on by default? Locking is for me not iteressting at this point.